# Como gerar um array de anos dinamicamente contendo o índice como o ano e o valor como o proprio ano?

Tags: php, array

Tenho uma rotina que gera uma lista de anos dinamicamente a partir de um ano inicial definido no array que neste caso é o ano de 2015 até o ano atual.

Veja a estrutura do array:

```
$rray = array(
            "1" => "2015" #Ano inicial
        );
```

Rotina que gera a lista de anos:

```
<?php
$rray = array(
            "1" => "2015"
        );

$ano = $rray[1];
$i = 1;

while ($ano <= date("Y")) {
    $rray[$i] = $ano;
    $ano++;
    $i++;
}

print_r($rray);
```

A rotina acima gera o seguinte array de saída:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2015
    [2] => 2016
    [3] => 2017
)
```

Porem eu gostaria que os índices que são numéricos `[1] [2] [3]` fossem o próprio ano.

Ao invés de ser

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2015
    [2] => 2016
    [3] => 2017
)
```

eu gostaria que fosse

```
Array
(
    [2015] => 2015
    [2016] => 2016
    [2017] => 2017
)
```

De qual forma eu poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode usar `range()` para gera a lista de anos e `array_combine()` para transformar o valor de `$keys` nas próprias chaves:

```
$keys = range(2015, 2020);
$arr = array_combine($keys , $keys);
```

Ou ainda:

```
$year = date('Y');
$keys = range($year, $year + 10);
$arr = array_combine($keys , $keys);
```

Saida:

```
Array
(
    [2015] => 2015
    [2016] => 2016
    [2017] => 2017
    [2018] => 2018
    [2019] => 2019
    [2020] => 2020
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Pode fazer dessa forma também, bem simples.

Código:

```
<?php

$rray = array();
$ano = '2015';

while ($ano <= date('Y')) {
    $rray[$ano] = $ano;
    $ano++;
}

print_r($rray);

?>
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [2015] => 2015
    [2016] => 2016
    [2017] => 2017
)
```